# how to implement single program multiple data (spmd) in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallel-python, dispy

i read the multiprocessing doc. in python and found that task can be assigned to different cpu cores. i like to run the following code (as a start) in parallel.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def do(a):
    for i in range(a):
        print i    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc1 = Process(target=do, args=(3,))
    proc2 = Process(target=do, args=(6,))
    proc1.start()   
    proc2.start()
```

now i get the output as 1 2 3 and then 1 ....6. but i need to work as 1 1 2 2  ie i want to run proc1 and proc2 in parallel (not one after other).

Answer (score 0):

So you can have your code execute in parallel just by using `map`.  I am using a delay (with `time.sleep`) to slow the code down so it prints as you want it to.  If you don't use the sleep, the first process will finish before the second starts… and you get `0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5`.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> p = Pool()
>>> 
>>> def do(a): 
...   for i in range(a):
...     import time
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print i
... 
>>> _ = p.map(do, [3,6])
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
4
5
>>>
```

I'm using the `multiprocessing` fork `pathos.multiprocessing` because I'm the author and I'm too lazy to code it in a file.  `pathos` enables you to do `multiprocessing` in the interpreter, but otherwise it's basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the library pp. I prefer pp over multiprocessing because it allows for parallel processing across different cpus on the network.  A function (func) can be applied to a list of inputs (args) using a simple code:

```
job_server=pp.Server(ncpus=num_local_procs,ppservers=nodes)
result=[job() for job in job_server.submit(func,input) for arg in args]
```

You can also check out more examples at: https://github.com/gopiks/mappy/blob/master/map.py